# Looping and adding an extension to all files using bash

Tags: bash

I have bunch of email file spread recursively within folders and subfolder, I need to add the extension .eml to all of them except the directories, so now what I have is the following

This loops through the directories recursively and list only the filenames

```
find a/ -name "*" -type f
```

How can I rename the filenames with the .eml extension?

I have this script that does what I want but it does not work recursively

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in * do 
e=`echo $i.eml`
echo $e
mv $i $e
done
```

How do I combine the 2?

Comment: do you want a file called foo.bar to be called foo.bar.eml or foo.eml?  That changes the answer you are looking for...

Comment: Why is your script so verbose?  You can do: `for i in *; do mv $i $i.ml; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With many versions of `find`, you can write:

```
find a/ -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}.eml' \;
```

Comment: `-name "*"` is unnecessary.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Yes, good point. I just used the OP's command and added what was needed, but I guess I might as well remove that part . . .